# Proof by counter-example

Tags: examples-counterexamples

As is probably obvious by the title I cannot work out any set of numbers which disporoves the following conjecture

$$ a^2 > b^2 => a > b $$

where A and B are real numbers.

Anyone to give a push in the right direction as I'm reaching the point of insanity with this probably simple question.

Comment: What happens if one of them is negative?

Comment: then you would get an imaginary number when you square root it

Comment: Try $a=-3$ $b=-2$. There are infintely many more.

Comment: So you can go from left to right even with the implication sign as it is

Comment: You should go from left to right because of the implication,if you had $\iff$ you could've started from both sides.

Comment: Choose any $a,b$ such that $a<b<0$. For example, if $a=-2$ and $b=-1$ then $a^2=4>1=b^2$ but $a\not>b$.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2 > b^2 \implies a^2-b^2 =(a-b)(a+b) >0 $ and this last is true when either .....